# servicestack ormlitecache on sqlserver cacheentry primary key

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In my web application i have used servicestack ormlite cache client on sql server. Yesterday my sql server get stuck at 99% of CPU and the thing that helped me to restore everything was to delete cacheentry table.
I have noticed that primary key of cacheentry table was varchar(8000). Do you think this can be the cause of my problem? I know that sql server suggests to use primary key not so big.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No only the length of the key stored in **varchar** fields contributes to the storage size, from [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql):

> The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

The `Id` of the ServiceStack's [CacheEntry](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/619f6825430752995d00407acbc352265a78270f/src/ServiceStack.Server/Caching/OrmLiteCacheClient.cs#L468) table is typically small where it's either a user-defined cache key or if you're using ServiceStack's [[CacheResponse]](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute) attribute it's the relative URL + any modifiers.